# Single query that will gather information from multiple tables and display it according to data from a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an image website, where users can upload images into public groups with basic functionality such as likes etc. I am currently building a statistics page for said groups and ideally need a single query that can get all of the likes from all of the images in a group.

**Tables**(with sample data below)

```
Group_images: ID | GROUP_ID | IMAGE_ID | TIMESTAMP
               1 |    1     |    10    | 1346256053


Likes: ID | USER_ID | IMAGE_ID | TIMESTAMP
        1 |    1    |   10     | 1346256090

Images : ID | HEADING | UPLOADER | FILENAME | EXT | TIMESTAMP
         10 | Cats    |    4     | 82375dss | .png| 134625400
```

So in theory it should do something like this,

Search for any images in `group_images` where `group_id` = '$id' --> gather all the images that are linked to the group --> search `likes` for all likes that have been associated with the group by searching for any that have a matching `image_id` from the first query.

I hope i have made this clear, if not please feel free to ask more questions and i will update the question with further details you need. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I have added sample data below the tables, what i would like to achieve is to be able to see all the user_id's from all the likes from group id = 1.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute. edited, let me know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this with a simple sub query. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a very fundamental SQL concept called  `JOIN` as well as aggregation (`COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, and a ton of others that you don't need right now).

```
SELECT
   HEADING, UPLOADER, FILENAME, EXT, COUNT(Likes.*)
FROM
   Group_Images gi
   JOIN Images i ON (gi.IMAGE_ID = i.ID)
   JOIN Likes l ON (i.ID = l.IMAGE_ID)
WHERE
   gi.ID = ?
GROUP BY
   i.ID
```

Comment: I am getting this response, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM Group_Images gi JOIN Images i ON (gi.IMAGE_ID = i.ID) JOIN Like' at line 2

Comment: That's weird .. try just changing `Likes.*` to `l.ID`.

Comment: My mistake. one sec will try it out.

Comment: You can't use `?`,  you need to replace that with whatever it's supposed to be (hopefully using prepared statements with php's `PDO` or something).  Not to be mean, but instead of copying/pasting a response, do a little research into its intent.  You won't learn unless you understand.

Comment: Yeah sorry i was just testing it in phpmyadmin then will peal it apart and see how it works, i understand your frustration and once again apologise.

Comment: It is not displaying the result i was expecting, as said in the question, i need it to return all of the likes that are associated with a group, for example, 4 people like 2 pictures in a group called cats(group_id = 2) I want to be able to search by group_id(2) and it will show all 4 likes.

Comment: Update the `GROUP BY`.  Right now it's grouping by the images themselves.  It sounds like you want to group by the groups_images.  You can also update the query to include `COUNT(i.ID)` as a column, which should give you the 4 likes and 2 people.

Comment: That isn't giving the desired output either, all i need is the information from the `likes` table where a image has been liked that is in the group.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15976/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-user1527354)